# Determining Shared Hosting Providers on an IP range

Tags: ip-address, shared-hosting

I have virtually the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300504/finding-out-all-websites-hosted-by-a-webhosting-service ... I'm trying to get shared hosting on a particular set of IPs because then my website will be close to another server on their network which my website needs to access.

I tried getting in touch with the cust. dept of the "BIG" hosting provider, but they they say that every client of theirs is like a black - box, so they dont know who does what with their server.

It doesnt make sense for me to get dedicated hosting > $2k or so at this stage, hence the question - who all is hosted there, and maybe one of them does provide reasonable shared hosting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reliable way to find out. You can try checking reverse dns (`dig -x <ip>`) to get clues in domain name, or querying their http server with ip as host.

Another way is to use domain databases, like http://www.domaintools.com/reverse-ip/ but there is no guarantee that they will have domain of the hoster in the list.

EDIT: fixed typo

Comment: Oh, sorry, its misspelled dig, which is dns query tool from bind package.
There are numerous web-services which can do this lookup for you if you dont have tools available, like http://remote.12dt.com/